# How do I fix this error: "Undefined function or variable 'NaN'"?

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm getting an error message in the yellow highlighted region that says *"Undefined function or variable 'NaN'".*

The purpose of this code is to determine the amount of change to give back to a customer.  This is based on how much an item costs and how much was paid.  Also, the code should return a flag saying if the transaction was completed.

This isn't all of my code, but I didn't want to make this longer than necessary.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

---

```
function [Change, flag] = makeChange(Cost, Paid)


extra = Paid-Cost;

if extra > 0
    Change = extra;    
    flag = true;
elseif extra == 0
    Change = 0;
    flag = true;
    return
else
   flag = false;
   Change = NaN;
   warning('That''s not enough to buy that item.');
   return

end
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `NaN` is a construct that is part of MATLAB.  Try doing `clear NaN` and try again.  You may have a variable that is overshadowing that construct somewhere.

Comment: Could not confirm with `Octave 3.8.1`

Comment: I replaced NaN with [ ] and that gave me the correct output, However would it be considered overshadowing of the variable name "Change" when its used in a a while loop later in the code. Also would overshadowing still apply even if my code doesn't include classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't confirm the problem with `Octave 3.8.1`.

```
octave:1> makeChange.m
error: 'Paid' undefined near line 4 column 9
error: called from:
error:   /Path/to/makeChange.m at line 4, column 7
octave:1> Cost = 5
Cost =  5
octave:2> Paid = 10
Paid =  10
octave:3> [change, completed] = makeChange(Cost, Paid)
change =  5
completed =  1
octave:4> Cost = 10
Cost =  10
octave:5> Paid = 5
Paid =  5
octave:6> [change, completed] = makeChange(Cost, Paid)
warning: That's not enough to buy that item.
change = NaN
completed = 0
```

I would recommend reformatting your code to the following:

```
function [Change, flag] = makeChange(Cost, Paid)

Change = Paid-Cost;
flag = true;

if Change < 0
   flag = false;
   Change = NaN;
   warning('That''s not enough to buy that item.');
   return
else
   return
end
```

By refactoring, you save yourself some needless comparisons, assignments, and logic.